# D3 How to group by unique names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Data**

```
newdata = [
   {'Name':'Andrew', 'Country':'US', 'Start date':'2012-7-2','Total':'30days'
}, {'Name':'Kat', 'Country':'US', 'Start date':'2012-2-2','Total':'24days'
}, {'Name':'Barry', 'Country':'France', 'Start date':'2012-12-2','Total':'22days'
}, {'Name':'Ash', 'Country':'US', 'Start date':'2015-2-2','Total':'20days'
}, {'Name':'Lucy', 'Country':'UK', 'Start date':'2016-2-2','Total':'35days'
}, {'Name':'Gerry', 'Country':'US', 'Start date':'2016-2-2','Total':'40days'
}, {'Name':'Alex', 'Country':'France', 'Start date':'2016-2-2','Total':'28days'
}, {'Name':'Morgan', 'Country':'UK', 'Start date':'2012-6-2','Total':'24days'
}];
```

I would like to be able to create a group for each different 'Country' (3 in total) and then to populate each of the groups with the 'Name' belonging to them.

My question is how can I return the unique names for 'Country' to create the groups?

I've had success creating the 3 groups using d3.map() when binding the data but this stripped out the rest of the values

https://jsfiddle.net/hellococomo/3d1asL4d/2/

**Code**

```
var canvas = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 350)
  .attr('height', 600)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,20)')

var country = canvas
  .selectAll(".country")
  .data(newdata)

var countryEnter = country
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class', 'country')

countryEnter
  .append("text")
  .attr('class', 'name')

country.select('.name')
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d.Country;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return i * 30;
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Nesting worked for me. As Cyril suggested, I used d3.nest() to create keys from 'Country'. I also decided to use div and p here instead of svg:g

**New working code**

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
  .entries(newdata);
   console.log(nested_data)

var canvas = d3.select('#chart')
  .attr('width', 350)
  .attr('height', 600)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,20)')

var country = canvas
  .selectAll(".country")
  .data(nested_data)

var countryEnter = country
  .enter().append('div')
  .attr('class', 'country')

countryEnter
  .append("p")
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .style('font-weight', 'bold')
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d.key;
  })

countryEnter.selectAll('.name')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter().append('p')
    .attr('class', 'name')
     .text(function(d) {
      return d.Name;
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your data using nest

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
.entries(newdata);
console.log(nested_data)
```

Hope this helps!

This should help you more http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/